# What do Spring MVC controllers send back to jQuery get/post calls?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

When I use Spring MVC with "traditional" (non-AJAX, page-reload-after-every-button-click) websites/apps, I usually define a controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someURL", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateThreshold(@RequestParam("x") String whatever) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    max.setView("someView");

    // Inject some models into the view.

    return mav;
}
```

Then I write a JSP view (`someView.jsp`) and have it use the Spring tags/models "injected" by the controller.

But with jQuery, you have GET/POST requests firing off, and expecting to simply update some portion of the DOM. I'm wondering two things:

- With jQuery, what "view" does the Spring MVC controller set (`mav.setName(...)`) and return? In other words, there's no new "view" since its an AJAX call for the same page/view. The jQuery result just needs to update the existing page/view.
- If there's a server-side error (i.e., some `@RequestParam` has an illegal value), how does the MVC controller return an error message that the jQuery can then use and display to the end user?

I'm a visual learner, so code snippets (both client-side jQuery and server-side controller/view) are *enormously* appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: it can return many different thigns, http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring MVC doesn't care whether the request is a "traditional" request or an AJAX request. Except for some potential additional header, both types of requests are exactly the same.

So, if you need to refresh part of a page using an AJAX request, you would use a controller like you're doing for a "traditional" page, and then forward to a view which generates the markup for the part of the page that must be refreshed. So instead of generating a complete HTML page, from `<html>` to `</html>`, the view would only generate a portion of a page.

You could also send make the controller return something other than HTML markup: XML or JSON for example. In that case, it would be up to the JavaScript function handling the response to use the received data and update the page DOM.

The errors are handled exactly the same way as for "traditional" requests as well. If there is a `500` error for example, it's up to the JavaScript code handling the AJAX response to do what it finds appropriate. For example, displaying an alert popup or something like that.